# What are the file formats that read into R the fastest?

Tags: r, csv, load, readr, rdata

It seems most intuitive that .rdata files might be the fasted file format for R to load, but when scanning some of the stack posts it seems that more attention has been on enhancing load times for .csv or other formats. Is there a definitive answer?

Comment: This is a very difficult question to answer correctly.  You  need to consider converting any given file-reading function into compiled & optimized c- or Fortran code, for example.   In addition,  since you generally don't have a choice of input format unless you generated the files **in R** in the first place, I'm not sure the answer really matters!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a definitive answer, but below are times it took to load the same dataframe read in as a `.tab` file with `utils::read.delim()`, `readr::read_tsv()`, `data.table::fread()` and as a binary `.RData` file timed using the `system.time()` function:

## `.tab` with `utils::read.delim`

```
system.time(
  read.delim("file.tab")
)
#   user  system elapsed 
# 52.279   0.146  52.465
```

## `.tab` with `readr::read_tsv`

```
system.time(
  read_tsv("file.tab")
)    
#   user  system elapsed 
# 23.417   0.839  24.275
```

## `.tab` with `data.table::fread`

At @Roman 's request the same ~500MB file loaded in a blistering 3 seconds:

```
system.time(
  data.table::fread("file.tab")
)
# Read 49739 rows and 3005 (of 3005) columns from 0.400 GB file in 00:00:04
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.078   0.092   3.172
```

## `.RData` binary file of the same dataframe

```
system.time(
  load("file.RData")
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.181   0.028   2.210
```

Clearly not definitive (sample size = 1!) but in my case with a 500MB data frame:

1. Binary `.RData` is quickest
2. `data.frame::fread()` is a close second
3. `readr::read_tsv` is an order of magnitude slower
4. `utils::read.x` is slowest and only half as fast as `readr`

Comment: I wonder how `fread` would handle this? Care to give it a go?

Comment: @Phil I'm pretty sure that specifying the `colClasses` will improve the read time of the tsv files. It might be worthwhile to include this comparison.

Comment: But how long did it take for R to **generate** each file type?  As I mentioned up top,  this comparison is moot when someone else sends you files in a given format.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. Pretty stark differences between.